# error: property 'myBoolVariableName' with 'retain' attribute must be of object type

Tags: objective-c, iphone, boolean

I have a BOOL value inside my @interface definition in my .h file.  Here it is below.  It has the same problem whether it's a pointer or not.

```
@interface myCustomViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
{
 //...more iboutlets defined above
 BOOL *myBoolVariableName;
}
```

When I compile, I get "error: property 'myBoolVariableName' with 'retain' attribute must be of object type" on the line for the import of my .h file.

I found this page here about an integer / nsnumber:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1846927

So, it seems I can't use BOOL values inside an @interface definition.  What can I use instead?

What should I do for BOOL / boolean values?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm guessing that later in your interface you have something like this:

```
@property (retain) BOOL *myBoolVariableName;
```

That means make a property who's value is a pointer to a BOOL, and use retain semantics.

Your problem is that BOOL * is a pointer to a byte of memory, not a pointer to an object. And retain is something that applies only to objects.

Here's how you can make a BOOL property.

```
@interface myCustomViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    BOOL myBoolVariableName;
}

@property myBoolVariableName;

@end
```

The important differences are that the variable is declared as "BOOL", not "BOOL *" and the property doesn't have (retain).

Comment: I had to do it like this, but otherwise you're dead on right.  :)  THank you.

@property BOOL myBoolVariableName;

Comment: This will also apply to Integers

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar situation. I solved it like,

```
@interface myCustomViewController : UIViewController {
BOOL myBoolVariableName;
}
@property BOOL myBoolVariableName;
@end
```

I refer one answer by Jon Hess but I got one error in it. Type name requires a specifier or qualifier.
My previous version was like,

```
@property myBoolVariableName;
```

So I added `BOOL` and solved the issue.