# list of object types for iphone sdk programming

Tags: iphone, types, object

Can anyone link to or list out the object types that the iphone sdk has built in?  For the moment I'm just looking for the simple data types.  I'm looking for variable types that are accepted in @interface definitions and also can be made into properties.

For example: NSNumber is for integers, right?  BOOL is for booleans.

What are the rest of the simple data types I can use?

Comment: Please look at this question too.
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338270/error-property-myboolvariablename-with-retain-attribute-must-be-of-object-ty

  
and this:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1846927

  
where someone posted this:

NSInteger is not an object - it's just typedef window dressing for a underlying primitive. Primitives cannot be retained, released, placed in NSArrays or any other of the automatic Cocoa goodness that you can do with objects.

Use NSNumber if you want an object that handles numbers and use intValue to get an int from it.

Comment: So that made me want to know more about what basic OBJECT data types I could use with "automatic Cocoa goodness" like being put in interfaces and NSArrays.  I'd like to know how to do floats, integers, doubles?, chars, strings, etc...  I'd expect there is a simple list somewhere.  I have read the intro to objective C page, but it hasn't stuck yet so I should revisit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer the question about what can go into a `@interface` and a `@property` definition.

Short answer; any C type, plus some Objective-C additions:

- `SEL & IMP` - Method selectors, and method implementation pointer.
- `id` - The object instance pointer.
- `Class` & `Protocol` - The meta class, and protocol instance pointers.

These have special meaning, anything else is just a sub-type of these.

For the access modifiers to `@property`:

- `assign` - Any type.
- `retain` - Only an `id` type, conforming to the `NSObject` protocol.
- `copy` - Only an `id` type, conforming to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: Wow.  That sort of makes my question unnecessary.  :)  Now I understand it a bit more.  I just need to make sure I don't use retain with non NSObject types.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is your friend, depending on your current skills you should also read the [Objective-c 2.0 Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html), read the Getting Started documents or look at the sample code. For C/Objective-C you have the basic datatypes you would expect int, float, double, char. NSArray and NSDictionary are pretty important for storing things, their changeable counterparts NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary are useful. NSNumber is a wrapper so your basic types can be used where objects are used (to put them in an NSArray for example)